# Read from a searchable pdf, without ocr

Tags: pdf

I'm currently using my scanner to turn my PDFs into searchable PDFs. The OCR is already taken care of, since I can use ctrl-f within the PDF.

How can I get at the OCR'd content from my program though.

I'm open to using java, ruby, the question is kind of programming language agnostic. Is the OCR'd text openly accessible by reading the file?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how your OCR software creates the PDF, but could you use a [third-party library (jPedal)](http://www.jpedal.org/) or tool such as [iText](http://itextpdf.com) or [XPDF](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/) to extract the text from the resulting PDF?

Comment: thanks. Itext can do it as well apparantly, just got it to work

Comment: I actually meant to include iText first, but must have accidentally edited it out before pressing 'add.' Added it to the answer for completeness, though. Glad it helped!